# python import prometheus_client with error "No module named 'prometheus_client'

Tags: python, prometheus

I follow the tutorial https://blog.techbridge.cc/2019/08/26/how-to-use-prometheus-grafana-in-flask-app/ to setup flask app and import prometheus module. But when I run the `sudo docker-compose up` command, it shows `ImportError: No module named 'prometheus_client'`

python code:

```
mport prometheus_client
from prometheus_client import Counter
from flask import Response, Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

total_requests = Counter('request_count', 'Total webapp request count')

@app.route('/metrics')
def requests_count():
     total_requests.inc()
     return Response(prometheus_client.generate_latest(total_requests), mimetype='text/plain')

@app.route('/')
def index():
     total_requests.inc()
     return jsonify({
         'status': 'ok'
     })

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

---

```
docker-compose up
Starting mkdirdocker-compose-python-flask-redis-counter_web_1 ... done
Attaching to mkdirdocker-compose-python-flask-redis-counter_web_1
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
web_1  |     import prometheus_client
web_1  | ImportError: No module named 'prometheus_client'
mkdirdocker-compose-python-flask-redis-counter_web_1 exited with code 1
```

---

```
howard@howard-virtual-machine:~/Desktop/mkdir docker-compose-python-flask-redis-counter$ pip install prometheus_client
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: prometheus_client in /home/howard/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (0.16.0)
```

It seems not work, so I try this way stiil not work.

```
python3 -m pip install prometheus-client --target=/home/howard/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages prometheus_client
Collecting prometheus-client
  Using cached prometheus_client-0.16.0-py3-none-any.whl (122 kB)
Installing collected packages: prometheus-client
Successfully installed prometheus-client-0.16.0
```

I have check the `pip list` the module exisd

[image]

Comment: Check if you possibly have multiple python versions installed
When I installed Python 3.11 without uninstalling Python 3.9, I had many import errors that I fixed by uninstalling Python 3.9

Comment: how can I check? 
pip --version pip 23.0 from /home/howard/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
pip3 --version
pip 23.0 from /home/howard/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)

Comment: You are calling pip from your host account not in the docker container. Did you follow the construction of the image from the dockerfile ?